# I cant understand these Pythagoras octave ratios

Tags: theory

So the book I am reading has this paragraph [image]

This book mentions Pythagoras ratios 1/8 , 1/4 , 1/3 , 1/2 , 2/3, 7/8 , 1

now when I go online, i can not find these ratios anywhere online.
All online resources have same ratios as this website below :
[https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~gibson/Notes/Section3_4/Sec3_4.htm](https://www.phys.uconn.edu/%7Egibson/Notes/Section3_4/Sec3_4.htm)

Please tell me whats going on here?

WHy is book ratios different than the website ratios?
[image]
help me understand this.
thanks

Comment: Please add the title and author of the book to help future searches.

Comment: @Aaron some googling suggests that it comes from Russell A. Smith's _Gurdjieff: Cosmic Secrets_. I'm afraid it might not be the best source to learn about music, in particular not about the practice of performing music.

Comment: For what it's worth, many of those ratios are decidedly un-Pythagorean.  Pythagorean ratios involve powers of 2 and 3 only, so there is no 5:4 ratio in the Pythagorean system.  Instead, that pitch is tuned at an 81:64 ratio to the fundamental.  Similarly, 5:3 and 15:8 are not Pythagorean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book presents numbers in a bit confusing way.

For example, they write "1/8 (1 + 1/8)" for natural (major) second. The value in the parenthesis is the actual ratio of the frequencies, 1+1/8, and that equals to 9/8.

It seems that the book and the webpage you quote present two different types of [just intonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_intonation): the book presents [five-limit tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-limit_tuning), while the webpage shows [Pythagorean tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_tuning).

> I still dont get how to derive 32/27 ratio, 27/16 and so on

The two tunings are only partially compatible, but at least some ratios are the same. The ratio of 32/27 is between D (re) and F (fa), that's a minor third, not given explicitly in your book. To calculate it, one can take the frequency ratio between F and C (1+1/3 = 4/3), and divide it by the frequency ratio between D and C (9/8). Then ratio between F and D is therefore (4/3) / (9/8) = 32/27.

Various types of tunings have different interval sizes. Moreover, with the exception of [equal temperament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament#Twelve-tone_equal_temperament), the same interval between different notes may have different sizes. For example, in five-limit tuning the frequency ratio for major second C-D is 9/8 = 1.125, but for major second, G-A it is (5/3) / (3/2) = 10/9 ≈ 1.111. A notable example of contradicting results when adding intervals in Pythagorean tuning is [Pythagorean comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_comma).

By the way, there is an inaccuracy in the page you included: *Music starts with 1 vibration per second* — not really. The lowest frequency a human ear can hear is around 20 Hz, and it's still quite low. For example, the fundamental frequency of the lowest note of bass guitar in standard tuning, E1, is 41.2 Hz.

As a final note, some authors have very strong opinions about the superiority of some tunings over the others, and comparing various sources — as you did — is a good idea.

Comment: I still dont get how to derive 32/27 ratio, 27/16 and so on by the book ratios even after adding 1 to those book ratios, for example adding 1 + 7/8 is 15/8 which is no where to be found on website ratios.

Comment: @administr4tor see the edited version of the answer

Comment: thanks for replying, what do you call those ratios mentioned in the book and what do you call those ratios mentioned in the website.

Comment: @administr4tor after looking carefully, I realize the book and the webpage present two different types of tuning. Answer updated.

Comment: 4/3 is 1+1/3, not 1+1/4.  Also (as you imply, but it's worth saying out loud) the second is a very terrestrial unit of measure, not a cosmic one.  The premise that music "starts" at any given frequency (using any given unit of time) is both absurd and unnecessary.

Comment: Furthermore, not only are those sets of ratios different types of tuning; they are also different scales.  The 5-limit ratios describe a major scale while the 3-limit ratios describe a (melodic, ascending) minor scale.  The Pythagorean major third is 81:64.

Comment: @phoog thanks, fixed the typo.